# Outdoor porch light problem

Tags: light

My light (LED) burned out, I think and when I replaced it  the light would not work.  Then, when I put in a regular light, it would go on for a second or more and
then flash three times and go out again.  Very frustrating
because I really want the light to work!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A regular, incandescent bulb reliably flashes three times? Then something else is going on that you haven't told us; please give us more info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Seems like you might have a short rather than a light bulb problem.

Comment: Is there a dusk to dawn sensor?

Comment: does it work in the dark? does the bulb you took out work elsewhere?